# mail interface cancel button not working ios - MFMailComposeViewController class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a webview object (aWebView) which was added on top of current window like this -

```
UIWindow *webWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320,460)];
[webWindow addSubview:aWebView];
[webWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have a ViewController (viewcontrollerobj) which is subView of aWebView -

```
[webView addSubview:viewcontrollerobj.view];
```

Then I am calling sendInAppMail method in the ViewController-

```
[sviewcontroller sendInAppMail];
```

SendInAppMail looks like this -

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        [mailController setMessageBody:@"hello" isHTML:NO];
        [mailController setSubject:@"subject"];
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;  
        [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
        [mailController release];
    }
```

didFinishWithResult looks like this -

```
- (void)mailComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Mail viewcontroller shows up fine. The problem is that when I hit cancel it shows the delete/save draf t option and after clicking either delete/save the mail viewcontroller doesn't go away!

When I look at console it shows this log message -
"Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:]."
I am not using UIActionSheet anywhere and haven't used in the past so I am not able to understand what it is saying.

I looked at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6015957/516938
But it seems like the solution given is very specific to a situation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is the issue, but this is the first thing I would look at.

Based on the error message that you got it sounds like either one of the views (the `aWebView` or the one from `viewcontrollerobj` that you defined) doesn't allow enough space for the `MFMailComposeViewController`, meaning that the dimensions of it are smaller than the `MFMailComposeViewController` requires. It isn't actually clipping the content, so you see it, but it is blocking the touches so that they don't get to the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

I hope that is clear enough - I had a hard time describing my thoughts here correctly.

Comment: I dont think its blocking the touches. Because when I hit cancel for the first time it shows delete/save draft option. I ran it again with NSLOg statement in didFinishWithResult and it seems like its not being called at all. Ideally, when I hit delete draft it should be called and the whole Mail dialog should disappear!

Comment: OMG! Silly mistake its "mailComposeController" and NOT "mailComposeViewController"

Comment: Haha! Oops. Glad you found the issue.